# C- implicit declaration of functions time, rand, printf, all of my function calls

Tags: c, declaration, implicit

This has been eating at me all day. I'm relatively new to C, and I CANNOT get this working and I have no idea why. I have 3 files..

I also want to apologize for the spacing as this is my first time using stack overflow... but anyways, here is the code...

assignment_1.h-----------------------------------------------------------

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENT_1_H
#define ASSIGNMENT_1_H

#define NULL 0

int CalculateFactorial(int input);
int CalculateFibonacci(int input);
void ReverseArray(int size, int array[]);
void ShuffleArray(int size, int array[]);

#endif
```

Main.c-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include "assignment_1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(){

int fact = CalculateFactorial(15);
int fib = CalculateFibonacci(15);

printf("Factorial: %d\n", fact);
printf("Fib: %d\n", fib);

int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int size = 6;

ReverseArray(size, array);
ShuffleArray(size, array);

return 0;


}/*end main*/
```

assignment_1.c---------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include "assignment_1.h"


int CalculateFactorial(int input){

if(input<=0)    return 0;


int factorial = input;
int multiplier = input;

while(multiplier > 1){
    factorial *= multiplier;
    --multiplier;
}/*end while*/

return factorial;

}/*end calcfact*/



int CalculateFibonacci(int input){

if(input<=0)    return 0;

else if(input == 1)     return 1;

return CalculateFibonnaci(input-1) + CalculateFibonacci(input-2);

}/*end calcfib*/



void ReverseArray(int size, int array[]){

int last = size-1;
int first = 0;
int temp;

while (last-first > 1){     /*stops the loop if size is even*/

temp = array[last];
array[last] = array[first];
array[first] = temp;

++first;
--last;

if(last-first == 2)     break; /*stops loop if size is odd*/

}/*end while*/

int i;
for (i = 0; i< size;++i){
    printf("%d, ",array[i]);
}
printf("\n");

}/*end reverse*/



void ShuffleArray(int size, int array[]){

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i){

    int idx = rand()%size; /*random unsigned int between 0 and the 
                        max index of the array*/

    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[idx];
    array[idx] = temp;

}/*end for loop*/

for (i = 0; i< size;++i){
    printf("%d, ",array[i]);
}
printf("\n");

}/*end shuffle*/
```

I keep getting a ton of errors all saying warning: implicit declaration of function '']

I greatly appreciate any help...

Comment: Can't see that but please note 1) You should not need to define `NULL` 2) `srand()` should be called once, at the start of the program, 3) a 32-bit `int` will not hold the value of `15!`.

Comment: You need to `#include` the headers for the functions used in `assignment_1.c` within `assignment_1.c` itself (or another header it includes).  It's ok to include them in both `.c` files if both files use those functions.

Comment: @Dmitiri,
I'm not too sure if I understand what you mean.. at the beginning of assignment1.c and main.c i have `#include "assignment_1.h"`

Comment: `assignment_1.h` has prototypes for the functions you define in `assignment_1.c`, but doesn't have declarations or includes for the library functions you call from those function definitions (like `printf()`).  So you need to include the required library headers in `assignment_1.c`, like you did in `main.c`.  (and `main.c` really only needs to include `assignment_1.h` and `stdio.h`, since the only standard library function it calls directly is `printf()`... `assignment_1.c` needs the other headers, though)

Comment: @Dmitri Thank you very much for your help. This made it work!

Comment: just because the Main.c file contains the needed header include statements does not mean those statements are carried forward to another file.  I.E. the assignment_1.c file needs `#include <time.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`  also note that the spelling of the function: `CalculateFonnaci() and `CalculateFobonacci() are not the same between the three files.

Comment: note the Fibonacci sequence is `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, etc.` NOT `0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, etc.`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're compiling assignment_1.c separately to main.c (which is reasonable if you plan on using a linker to link the two together once they're compiled), you need to include these headers in that file, *too*; they don't automatically carry over from one translation unit to the other.

Insert these into assignment_1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

---

I spotted an additional error, being the definition of `NULL` you specified in assignment_1.h; *you* should *never* define `NULL` yourself, as it's a standard symbol. That'd be like writing your own `printf` and `scanf`.

`NULL` is defined within the `<stddef.h>` header. Include that, too, when you want to use `NULL`.

Comment: I would also consider pointing out that `NULL` is implementation specific and isn't always equal to `0` (or `((void*)0x0)`)... it's a value that the operating system defines according to it's specific memory map translation design (though it ends up being defined as `((void*)0x0)` 99% of the time).

Comment: @Myst `NULL` is a null pointer constant, and by that definition it's *required* to compare equal to zero. I understand what you're saying, though; it might not have an underlying zero bit pattern. I don't consider that detail relevant enough to this question to inject it into an answer; if people want to read further, they'll see these comments fairly quickly. Ta :)

Comment: That's true :-)